# How to match all overlapping pattern

Tags: regex, go

I want to get the indexes of the following pattern `(\.\.#\.\.)` in the following string :

```
...#...#....#.....#..#..#..#.......
```

But Golang does not manage overlapping matching.

Thus I got : `[[1 6 1 6] [10 15 10 15] [16 21 16 21] [22 27 22 27]]`

As one can see, two points `.` do precede and suffix the second `#` but it's not return by the method `FindAllStringSubmatchIndex`.

I tried to use different methods from regexp without success. Searching the documentation, I found nothing useful on https://golang.org/pkg/regexp and https://golang.org/src/regexp/regexp.go

On the contrary, it seems regexp does not natively support this functionality :

> // If 'All' is present, the routine matches successive non-overlapping matches of the entire expression.

I can solve the issue but since I am doing this exercise to learn Golang, I want to know. thanks :)

Here is my code for reference :

```
        matches := r.pattern.FindAllStringSubmatchIndex(startingState)
        fmt.Println(r.pattern)
        fmt.Println(matches)
        for _, m := range matches {
            tempState = tempState[:m[0]+2] + "#" + tempState[m[0]+3:]
            fmt.Println(tempState)
        }
```

Comment: Don't use a regex for this. Use `strings.Index`, and a for loop.

Comment: The problem is that Go regex (powered by the RE2 engine) does not support lookarounds, and thus, you cannot match the same text more than once. You cannot solve it with a single, plain regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks that's the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no reason to use a regex for this. Regex is overkill for such a simple task--it's over complex, and less efficient. Instead you should just use [`strings.Index`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Index), and a for loop:

```
input := "...#...#....#.....#..#..#..#......."
idx := []int{}
j := 0
for {
    i := strings.Index(input[j:], "..#..")
    if i == -1 {
        break
    }
    fmt.Println(j)
    idx = append(idx, j+i)
    j += i+1
}
fmt.Println("Indexes:", idx)
```

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/aQAz0nJbgAx)

Comment: Thanks. So golang implementation of regexp don't do overlap ?

Comment: I don't know. There's just no reason ever to use a regex (in any language) for a problem this simple. Don't over-complicate your code.

Answer (score 3):

Go is for programmers. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func findIndices(haystack, needle string) []int {
    var x []int
    for i := 0; i < len(haystack)-len(needle); i++ {
        j := strings.Index(haystack[i:], needle)
        if j < 0 {
            break
        }
        i += j
        x = append(x, i)
    }
    return x
}

func main() {
    haystack := `...#...#....#.....#..#..#..#.......`
    needle := `..#..`
    fmt.Println(findIndices(haystack, needle))
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/nNE5IB1feQT

Output:

```
[1 5 10 16 19 22 25]
```

---

Regular Expression References:

[Regular Expression Matching Can Be Simple And Fast](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html)

[Implementing Regular Expressions](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/)

[Package [regexp/]syntax](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax/)

Comment: Thanks. So golang implementation of regexp don't do overlap ?

Comment: I have added regular expression references to my answer.

Comment: "Go is for programmers." so you have to write everything yourself?